# Empty Screenshots of Facebook with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I am using [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) (a nodejs implementation of CasperJS with the same API) to navigate to facebook's developer portal and return a list of all of my app keys and secrets. Everything works great up until my code takes me to developers.facebook.com/apps. Once I hit that page, the screenshots Spooky show the facebook header and footer, but no content in the body of the page is showing up despite it being present in the source code I download from the page using Spooky. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue