# CasperJS bind issue

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, instagram, casperjs

I'm trying to reach an instagram page, but with no luck. I keep getting the error and a blank screenshot.

Error text:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.createDescriptor.bind(null,t)')
```

Casperjs --version is 1.1.0-beta3.

Basically I use the following code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    },
    loadPlugins: true
});

casper.on( 'page.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});

casper.start('http://instagram.com/hello', function() {
    casper.wait(3000, function()  {
        this.capture('screen.png');
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The shim below isn't needed anymore if PhantomJS 2 is used. Sadly CasperJS 1.1-beta3 doesn't support it yet, so you might want to use the master branch from [GitHub](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs).

---

The problem is that PhantomJS v1.x does not support the `Function.prototype.bind`. You need to add a shim for that. In CasperJS it goes into the [`page.initialized`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-initialized) event handler. [This shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521) works well for me on instragram:

```
casper.on( 'page.initialized', function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        var isFunction = function(o) {
          return typeof o == 'function';
        };

        var bind,
          slice = [].slice,
          proto = Function.prototype,
          featureMap;

        featureMap = {
          'function-bind': 'bind'
        };

        function has(feature) {
          var prop = featureMap[feature];
          return isFunction(proto[prop]);
        }

        // check for missing features
        if (!has('function-bind')) {
          // adapted from Mozilla Developer Network example at
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
          bind = function bind(obj) {
            var args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
              self = this,
              nop = function() {
              },
              bound = function() {
                return self.apply(this instanceof nop ? this : (obj || {}), args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
              };
            nop.prototype = this.prototype || {}; // Firefox cries sometimes if prototype is undefined
            bound.prototype = new nop();
            return bound;
          };
          proto.bind = bind;
        }
    });
});
```

It doesn't work if the shim is exported into its own file and included through the [`clientScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clientscripts) option, because those are appended after the instagram javascript which is too late.

What might also work is registering to [`page.resource.received`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-received) event.

There is also the pure PhantomJS question: [bind polyfill for PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24224323/1816580)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer which also works well for facebook .

Comment: You might want to update PhantomJS to version 2 and use CasperJS from the master branch on GitHub.

Comment: Oh thanks for that, will this make this solution unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, it will make it unnecessary, but as I said currently there are some hurdles, because there is currently no CasperJS release that supports PhantomJS 2.

Comment: Just want to add a few tags for google to pickup incase anyone else is searching the wrong thing (as I was)

casperjs casper not rendering svg png transparent png not capturing no capture

Comment: @Frozenfire That shouldn't be necessary, because over time this question was asked in different ways and they were marked as duplicate of this question.

Comment: Well I wasn't able to find any that took me to here. My issue was SVGs not rendering and transparent PNG's as background-image showing up all white. Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: Unfortunately this will not polyfill iframe environments... just the parent window