# CasperJS doesn't execute javascript of page

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

So i just want to open a webpage , but a big part of it are scripts read by the browser...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>MyAccount</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
    // Here is the rest generated by the script. On chrome i can see it easily (inspect element)
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.myAccountUrl = "http://urlsample";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

but with casper nothing appear in it. I use this settings:

```
pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,    
        loadPlugins: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true,
        XSSAuditingEnabled: true
    }
```

And i render the html like that:

```
var js = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document; 
});
this.echo(js.all[0].outerHTML);
```

If anyone can help me, he's welcome. :)

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521). Maybe try to run CasperJS with `--web-security=false`.

Comment: Ok i will try this.
But i would like to remind that casperjs do render html, only without what's inside the container div.

Comment: Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'RegExp.prototype.test.bind(
    /^(data|aria)-[a-z_][a-z\d_.\-]*$/
  )')
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ux


So i get some errors, thx!
i will try to see what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS bind issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue)

Comment: Thx! that was it. I just learned that the site use reactJS, so that's why i had problems.