# Phantomjs page.content isn't retrieving the page content

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-scraping, phantomjs

I use Phantomjs to scrape websites that use JavaScript and Ajax to load dynamic content.
I have the following code:

```
  var page = require('webpage').create();
        page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
            var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
            if (trace && trace.length) {
                msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                trace.forEach(function(t) {
                    msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
                });
            }
            console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
        };
        page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
            console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
        };
        page.open('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/oberliga-bayern-sud/wolfratshausen-unterhaching-ii/x8rBMAB8/', function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        });
```

The problem is that this code doesn't retrieve the source code i want.
If you enter the URL through a web browser(like chrome) and read the source code(the dynamic source code, after the JavaScript and Ajax calls were made) of the page, you will see that the web browser source code and the Phantomjs source code are completely different.
But in this case i need the web browsers source code.
Usually this Phantomjs code retrieves the source code i need, but in the case of this url(any many others) Phantomjs does not retrieve the correct source code.
I assume Phantomjs doesn't know how to handle the JavaScript and Ajax calls that load dynamic content into this page.
I get these errors when i run the code:

```
ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'function(e){
        this.pointer.x = e.pageX;
        this.pointer.y = e.pageY;
    }.bind(this)')
TRACE:
 -> http://www.betexplorer.com/gres/tooltip.js?serial=1410131213: 207
 -> http://www.betexplorer.com/gres/tooltip.js?serial=1410131213: 157
 -> http://www.betexplorer.com/gres/tooltip.js?serial=1410131213: 310 (in function "tooltip")
 -> http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/oberliga-bayern-sud/wolfratshausen-unterhaching-ii/x8rBMAB8/: 291
 -> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js: 2
 -> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js: 2
 -> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js: 2
 -> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js: 2
CONSOLE: Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. (from line #undefined in "undefined")
CONSOLE: FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). (from line #undefined in "undefined")
```

So how do i get the dynamic source code of this page(http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/oberliga-bayern-sud/wolfratshausen-unterhaching-ii/x8rBMAB8/) using Phantomjs?

Comment: ok i registered to the onConsoleMessage and OnError events and updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the page is dynamically generated, you need to wait a little before you can access the intended page source.

```
page.open('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/oberliga-bayern-sud/wolfratshausen-unterhaching-ii/x8rBMAB8/', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000); // 5 sec should be enough
});
```

The `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` refers to `bind`, because PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support it. PhantomJS 1.x uses an old fork of QtWebkit which is comparable to Chrome 13 or Safari 5. The newer PhantomJS 2 uses a newer engine which supports `bind`. If you still use version 1.x you need to add a shim inside of the [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) event handler:

```
page.onInitialized = function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        var isFunction = function(o) {
          return typeof o == 'function';
        };

        var bind,
          slice = [].slice,
          proto = Function.prototype,
          featureMap;

        featureMap = {
          'function-bind': 'bind'
        };

        function has(feature) {
          var prop = featureMap[feature];
          return isFunction(proto[prop]);
        }

        // check for missing features
        if (!has('function-bind')) {
          // adapted from Mozilla Developer Network example at
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
          bind = function bind(obj) {
            var args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
              self = this,
              nop = function() {
              },
              bound = function() {
                return self.apply(this instanceof nop ? this : (obj || {}), args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
              };
            nop.prototype = this.prototype || {}; // Firefox cries sometimes if prototype is undefined
            bound.prototype = new nop();
            return bound;
          };
          proto.bind = bind;
        }
    });
};
```

Taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359714/1816580).