# PhantomJS page.open freezes

Tags: phantomjs, headless

I am trying to open a website using PhantomJS using the Capture example

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

The code works fine on my local machine, using Ubuntu 14.04. But when I run the code on a virtual server, the callback is never called and the script does not exit. The server and my local machine are running the exact same setup. I tried it on 2 different servers on virtualised with VMWare and one with Virtuozzo.

It does not seem to be a network error as all requests are successful.

Comment: Yay setting the UserAgent solved the problem. I would never have come up with this. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it seems you are using PhantomJS 1.9.8?

Comment: Jip I am using the latest version 1.9.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the UserAgent caused all the trouble. @artjom-b pointed me to this Question [Taking reliable screenshots of websites? Phantomjs and Casperjs both return empty screen shots on some websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517852/taking-reliable-screenshots-of-websites-phantomjs-and-casperjs-both-return-empt). The Only difference is that for me the image file was never created.

So setting the UserAgent with

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36';
```

actually solved the problem.