# Phantomjs does not open web page

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I have started testing [campus2020](http://informatik.uni-leipzig.de/campus2020/) site with casperjs (1.1.0-beta3) + phantomjs (1.9.8). And faced with the problem that site is not opening but instead tests just freeze. I have taken script example from phantomjs site:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://informatik.uni-leipzig.de/campus2020', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

It worked fine on other sites. I have tested opening the campus2020 site with phantomjs on several environments: win 7, Ubuntu 14.04, with ghostdriver and java selenium webdriver, with phantomjs which is run in selenium grid on RHEL 6.6. All this options failed. I have tried to add [userAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609450/phantomjs-page-open-freezes) option and [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517852/taking-reliable-screenshots-of-websites-phantomjs-and-casperjs-both-return-empt). Nothing changed. Also I tried to open this site using  testing framework based on selenium webdriver which used phantomjs but it worked in the same way - phantomjs initialized and then freezes. Any ideas how could be this issue solved?

### Update

Now my code looks like these:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log("Page is going to be opened...")
page.open('http://informatik.uni-leipzig.de/campus2020/', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
  console.log(msg);
  trace.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(' ', item.file, ':', item.line);
  })
}

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
        console.log('Response (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
    };
```

And no errors are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why there is this issue, but you can update to PhantomJS 2 and it will work. There are not yet binaries for Linux, so you will need to build it yourself.

You will also need to update your CasperJS version, because the 1.1-beta3 doesn't support PhantomJS 2, but the [master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs) does.

Answer (score 0):

phantomjs --debug=true phantom_test.js