# Phantomjs Function.prototype.bind

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

**Yes, I know that.** Function bind is not supported by Phantomjs. But maybe I can use something else, or say `page.open` not to use `bind`? It seems to be OK, but some websites 
return error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.bind(a)')
```

After that I wrote a simple script, which just opens a page:

```
var address = phantom.args[0];
if(!address) phantom.exit(1);

page = require("webpage").create();

page.open(address, function(status){
setInterval(
   function () {

   console.log(
       page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.body.innerHTML.length;
       })
   )}, 200)
})
```

But error is still there. Error is not the main problem, but the problem is to get page content, because after error page content is not loading...

So, I need help.

P.S. Problem website is http://vkrushelnytskiy.wix.com/aaaa

Comment: Why do you think that the page would load as nothing has happened when the bind error comes from `require.min.js`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phantomjs page.content isn't retrieving the page content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382041/phantomjs-page-content-isnt-retrieving-the-page-content)

Comment: ^ I tried it out with your URL and it works.

Comment: @ArtjomB., does it work on page.open??

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've tried and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There is an [npm package which loads a polyfill for phantomJS's missing .bind method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill). Copying the installation instructions here for convenience, but follow the link for any updates.

**Installation**

```
npm install --save-dev phantomjs-polyfill
```

**Usage**

```
require('phantomjs-polyfill')
```

**Usage with Karma**
Include the polyfill directly in the files list of your karma.conf

```
...
files: [
  './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
  ...
]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use this code as an alternative

if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shim Function.bind using the following [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

Just prepend it to the code you are trying to run. There are probably nicer solutions, but this worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can mention this bind function just before the test case.

```
// PhantomJS doesn't support bind yet
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind ||
  function (ctx) {
    var fn = this,
      args = [],
      param_length = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {    
    if(i){
      args[i-1] = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  param_length = args.length;
  return function () {
    for(var i =0; i<arguments.length; i++){
      args[param_length + i] = arguments[i];
    }
    return fn.apply(ctx, args);
  };
};
```