# I am getting the following error while accessing an angularJS app with casperjs: "Can't find variable: angular"

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is the complete error text:

> Page error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ModuleStore.register.bind(ModuleStore)')
>   Page error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular

I am using phantomJS 2.0 with casperjs 1.1-beta3

**UPDATE:** I had multiple phantomjs versions installed. When using `phantomjs -v` command, it was showing me 2.0.0 but when I used `casperjs` command, it showed me that casperjs is using different version.

Comment: are you absolutely sure angular is imported before anything that tries to use it?

Comment: Your error message suggests that you are using PhantomJS 1.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phantomjs page.content isn't retrieving the page content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382041/phantomjs-page-content-isnt-retrieving-the-page-content)

Comment: You are right @ArtjomB. It seems that casperjs was using different version of phantomjs while `phantomjs --version` was showing me 2.0.0 which caused the confusion. Thanks a lot, at last I got rid of that error.

Comment: Sorry, wrong duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue Although, it also applies.