# Can use casperjs login to facebook but capture to png only show nav bar

Tags: javascript, facebook, casperjs, capture

Can use casperjs login to facebook  but capture to png only show nav bar
this my code: facebook.js

```
casper.start("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(response) {
    if (this.exists('[name="lsd"]')) {              
        this.page.evaluate(function(a,b) {
              document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = a
              document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = b;
              document.querySelector("#login_form").submit(); 
              console.log("Login submitted!");
        },user_email,user_pass);                
    } else {
        this.echo('[name="lsd"] not found', 'ERROR');
        phantom.exit();
    }
    this.capture('img/'+user_email+'_login.png');
});

casper.run();
```

please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you immediately capture the page after submitting the login form. You need to wait a bit before the new page is loaded, but this is not the only problem with facebook.

1. You need to run CasperJS like this:

   ```
   casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 facebook.js
   ```

   because of the recent POODLE SSL vulnerability. ([Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419531/1816580))
2. When you register to [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), you see multiple errors popping up, saying that `bind` is not available. You need a shim for that so that facebook functions properly. I provided a copy paste solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359714/1816580).

And now the issue of waiting for the page to load... There are several solutions for this.

#### Add a step

This is the easiest and works on most non-single-page-apps.

```
casper.start("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(response) {
    this.page.evaluate(function(a,b) {
        // login
    }, user_email, user_pass);
}).then(function(){
    this.capture('img/'+user_email+'_login.png');
}).run();
```

#### Wait for a selector that exists only on the new page

This is the most robust way and works on all pages.

```
casper.start("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(response) {
    this.page.evaluate(function(a,b) {
        // login
    }, user_email, user_pass);
}).waitForSelector("SOMESELECTORLIKEPROFILEBUTTON", function(){
    this.capture('img/'+user_email+'_login.png');
}).run();
```

#### Wait a static amount of time

This is the least robust, but easiest. You may wait longer than necessary or not long enough so that the operation fails.

```
casper.start("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(response) {
    this.page.evaluate(function(a,b) {
        // login
    }, user_email, user_pass);
}).wait(4000, function(){
    this.capture('img/'+user_email+'_login.png');
}).run();
```

*Note: I'm using the promise syntax, but it is not necessary.*

Comment: I tried the above code, but still no success.
Could someone successfully before?

the use chrome capture img:

http://api.520sz.com/taobao/facebook_chrome.png 

the capture result png:
http://api.520sz.com/taobao/user_login1.png 

the all my code:
http://api.520sz.com/taobao/facebook.js

please help me.