# how to click on element in someones website with javascript(login to outlook.com)

Tags: javascript, dom, select, phantomjs, casperjs

forexample I can go to [msn.com](http://www.msn.com) and open developer tools and write this code `document.querySelector('.news a').click()` and it will open **news**.
Now I want a program to do this **automatically** for me. write a javascript code that do this for me
actully this was just a simple example I don't want a program to open news in msn actully I want to submit something automaticaly.
1)how can I do this (I know if want to make this app for desktop I should use something like appjs)? 2)Is there any way that it doesn't open browser and submit that?

***update:***

I tested casperjs(as mentioned in comments) and I tried to login to my outlook then capture  it.

here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("https://outlook.com", function(response) {
   this.page.evaluate(function(a,b) {
    // login

      document.querySelector('#i0116').value = a;
      document.querySelector('#i0118').value = b;
      document.querySelector('#idSIButton9').click();
   },'**********@outlook.com','**********');
}).then( function(){
       this.capture('outlook.png');
       this.echo(this.getTitle());
   }).run();
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503418/can-use-casperjs-login-to-facebook-but-capture-to-png-only-show-nav-bar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page/26419531#26419531) stackoverflow questions
I tried `casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test.js`  and `casperjs --ssl-protocol=any test.js` and `.wait(4000, function(){this.capture('outlook.png')}` but all of them loged **sign in** and the below picture[image]

as you see the sign in form is filled but it couldn't enter it.

In the developer tools I entered

```
      document.querySelector('#i0116').value = a;
      document.querySelector('#i0118').value = b;
      document.querySelector('#idSIButton9').click();
```

and it worked but here it doesn't work.

Comment: Using a plain browser TamperMonkey [chrome], Greasemokey [firefox] or a bookmarklet. You can use selenium. You can do it with phantomjs if you want to do it headless.

Comment: I tested casperjs and I have a new problem now