# Screenshot on a react page is blank using casperjs

Tags: casperjs, reactjs

I am trying to use casperjs on a react app and noticed that screenshots were coming back as blank. So, I tried a different app and got the same result.

So, here is a react app I found - http://jaredly.github.io/github-issues-viewer/#rails/rails/0 and here is the casperjs code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://jaredly.github.io/github-issues-viewer/#rails/rails/0', function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
  this.capture('im.png')
});
```

The image shows blank info

[image: screenshot of the page]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I added `page.error` event handler and it showed that it is a bind error. See this for a solution: [CasperJS bind issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue)