# PhantomJS is not executing JS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I try to make a screenshot of www.fallswoodsmith.com with PhantomJS. My code is:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.clipRect = {top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768};

page.open('http://www.fallswoodsmith.com', function () {
    page.render('cache/www.fallswoodsmith.com123567266_1024_768.png', {format: 'png', quality: '10'});
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This page is JS only, so without JS you get no content. For some reason PhantomJS is not executing this JS. I've also tried to set a timeout of 5 secs for the `page.render()` and `phantom.exit()`, but this did not change something. If I do a `console.log(page.content)` before the `page.render()` I get the full HTML of the page - just without changes that JS does.

Why does PhantomJS not execute the page's JS?

**UPDATE 1:**
I've added the following debug stuff:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {

    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
        });
    }

    console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));

};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
    console.log('Response (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};
```

No console.log() output in my console...

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've registered these events, but there's no output on my console... (see update1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I may politely ask, who made that site? I would very much recommend not building sites in such a way that they are 100% dependent on JavaScript. Turning off JavaScript and "loading" that site ([www.fallswoodsmith.com](http://www.fallswoodsmith.com)) results in nothing. zip. nada. zilch. `</rant>`

#### The answer you are looking for

Running the screenshot script you have above, I get the following output:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'joinURL.bind(null, staticServerUrl)')

  http://static.parastorage.com/services/santa-versions/1.150.0/main-r.js:353 in wixRenderSite
```

To fix that issue, you can polyfill [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) (which is missing from PhantomJS 1.x, [as per this issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522)) after the web page object is created but before a URL is loaded (i.e. [`onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html)).

The result:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onInitialized = function () {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        var isFunction = function (obj) {
            return typeof obj == 'function' || false;
        };
        var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
        Function.prototype.bind = function bind(obj) {
            var args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
            var self = this;
            var F = function () {};
            var bounded = function() {
                return self.apply(
                    this instanceof F ? this : (obj || {}),
                    args.concat(slice.call(arguments))
                );
            };
            F.prototype = this.prototype || {};
            bounded.prototype = new F();
            return bounded;
        };
    });
};

page.open('http://www.fallswoodsmith.com', function () {
    setTimeout(function screenshot() {
        page.render('WORKS.png', {
            format: 'png',
            quality: '10',
        });
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10 * 1000);
});
```

Why wait 10 seconds before taking a screenshot? Well, since the site is completely reliant on JS, there is no obvious event (that I can think of) to wait for that indicates the loading of the page. Your mileage may vary. Increase or decrease the timeout as you see fit.

Note: the output filename above is `WORKS.png`.

#### PhantomJS versions

The above example was tested and works with PhantomJS 1.9.7. The script seems to work with PhantomJS 1.9.8 as well, but 1.9.8 has [this issue (Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame in 1.9.8)](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697) that, while fixed, is not part of any release and causes the following error-looking output:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://28011634.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://28011634.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://28011634.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://28011634.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

#### Viewport size

By default, the rendered image will be a full page screenshot. To fix the viewport size, you can add back in the following at the top of the script:

```
page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
};
page.clipRect = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
};
```

#### Polyfilling `.bind`

The polyfill found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill), doesn't seem to work without a bit of modification, but that, combined with the underscore.js source code and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359714) resulted in the above.

Comment: I don't know the owner of this page. But it is made with wix.com and I think all there pages are built like that. And I totally agree that this is... not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.1 phantomjs has polyfill included into distribution's javascript engine. Try their [latest version](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).