# Blank screenshot in PhantomJS and Node.js with bind error

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to take a screenshot of [earth.nullschool.net](https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/isobaric/10hPa/orthographic=0.00,0.00,350) with PhantomJS and Node.js.

This is the relevant code:

```
var phantom = require("phantom");
var url = "http://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/isobaric/10hPa/orthographic=0.00,0.00,350";
var timeout = 15000;

phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.open(url, function(status) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                page.render("earth_0-0-350_#current.png", function(finished) {
                    ph.exit();
                });
            }, timeout);
        });
    });
});
```

I originally set the `timeout` variable to 5 seconds. This returned a blank image that hasn't rendered the map.

[image: earth not rendered]

I figured I needed a longer timeout to allow the page to fully load. So I have progressively made the timeout longer up to a full minute. But the output is the same. The map never renders.

After registering the event handlers (`onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout`) I found the following error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'i.bind(null,t,n)')
TRACE:
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 84
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 85
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 85
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 7 (in function "a")
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 7
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 84 (in function "n")
 -> http://earth.nullschool.net/js/bundle.min.js?v20150923: 64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS 1.x has a pretty old engine and doesn't support some essential web standards. Among those is `Function.prototype.bind` which is not supported. [This  shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521) which works for almost all cases.

Since you generally want to enable this as soon as possible, you have to run the shim from the [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) event listener. The invocation in phantomjs-node is a little different than in plain PhantomJS:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.set('onInitialized', function(success) {
            page.evaluate(function(){
                var isFunction = function(o) {
                  return typeof o == 'function';
                };

                var bind,
                  slice = [].slice,
                  proto = Function.prototype,
                  featureMap;

                featureMap = {
                  'function-bind': 'bind'
                };

                function has(feature) {
                  var prop = featureMap[feature];
                  return isFunction(proto[prop]);
                }

                // check for missing features
                if (!has('function-bind')) {
                  // adapted from Mozilla Developer Network example at
                  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
                  bind = function bind(obj) {
                    var args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
                      self = this,
                      nop = function() {
                      },
                      bound = function() {
                        return self.apply(this instanceof nop ? this : (obj || {}), args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
                      };
                    nop.prototype = this.prototype || {}; // Firefox cries sometimes if prototype is undefined
                    bound.prototype = new nop();
                    return bound;
                  };
                  proto.bind = bind;
                }
            });
        });

        /* remaining script */
        setTimeout(function() {
            page.render("earth_0-0-350_#current.png", function(finished) {
                ph.exit();
            });
        }, timeout);
    });
});
```

This is adjusted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359714/1816580).